# Is there a way to drag text from Google Docs to MS Word?

Tags: google-docs

What I tried to do is, select some text and drag and drop it to another MS Word 2003 document. The MS Word document was opened with MS Word 2003. It's really a pain to press control-c and click the MS field and press control-v again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, as you found out. But if you have a lot of text fragments to copy to a local MS Word, the following workaround might help:

1. Click File > Publish to the Web > Publish
2. Open the published document in another tab. Drag and drop from that page.
3. Click "Stop publishing".

Answer (score -2):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (on Windows) while dragging.

Comment: There is no try, as Yoda wisely said. Either you have an answer or you're just guessing -- in the latter case, expect downvotes.